# Parsing HTML5 data-* attribute values with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, selenium, custom-data-attribute

I am parsing a JS generated webpage like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.consumerbarometer.com/en/graph-builder/?question=M1&filter=country:singapore,canada,mexico,brazil,argentina,united_states,bulgaria,austria,belgium,croatia,czech_republic,denmark,estonia,finland,france,germany,greece,hungary,italy,ireland,latvia,lithuania,norway,netherlands,poland,portugal,russia,romania,serbia,slovakia,spain,slovenia,sweden,switzerland,ukraine,united_kingdom,australia,china,israel,hong_kong_sar,japan,korea,new_zealand,malaysia,taiwan,turkey,vietnam')

// wait for svg to appear
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'svg')))

for text in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('bar-text-label'):
    print(text.text)

driver.close()
```

Besides getting the `text` from the class `bar-text-label` I would also like to get values from an HTML5 data-attribute. For example,`<rect rx="3" ry="3" width="76%" height="40" transform="translate(0,40)" data-value="76" class="bar"></rect>` and I would like to be able to parse `76` from this.

Is this possible to do in Selenium?

I tried both of the below, with no sucess:

```
for text in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('bar'): 
    print(data_value.text)

for data in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@data-value)]/@data-value'): 
    print(data.text)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `.get_attribute()` method on the element after it has been located?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have elements like the following:

```
<rect rx="3" ry="3" width="76%" height="40" transform="translate(0,40)" data-value="75" class="bar">bar1</rect>
<rect rx="3" ry="3" width="76%" height="40" transform="translate(0,40)" data-value="76" class="bar">bar2</rect>
```

You can get the text value and the attribute value as follows:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('bar')
for element in elements:
    print element.text
    print element.get_attribute('data-value')
```

This prints out:

```
bar1
75
bar2
76
```

Answer (score 3):

You mention you tried:

```
for text in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('bar'): 
    print(data_value.text)
```

Seeing as `data_value` is not defined anywhere, it won't work. If you did `print(text.text)` you should get the text of each element that has a `bar` class. (This is essentially what you do in your first snippet.)

You also mention this:

```
for data in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@data-value)]/@data-value'): 
    print(data.text)
```

This cannot work because **Selenium's `find_element(s)...` functions cannot return anything else than elements or lists of elements**. You are trying to get it to return an attribute, which won't work. XPath generally allows it, but when you use XPath through Selenium you cannot get anything else than elements.

You could do what [Jessamyn Smith suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28327313/1906307) or:

```
results = driver.execute_script("""
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("bar");
    var ret = [];
    for (var i =0, el; (el = els[i]); ++i) {
        ret.push([el.textContent, el.attributes["data-value"].value]);
    }
    return ret;
""")
for r in results:
    print(r[0], r[1])
```

This will take one round-trip between your script and the browser. Looping and using `.text` and `.get_attribute()` involves 2 round-trips per iteration. The JavasScript builds a list of pairs of results. Each pair contains the text of the element in the first position, and the value of `data-value` in the second position.

Comment: This is very interesting.  I did not know you could execute js like that.

Comment: I did not know either at first. If you run everything locally, the difference is not great but if you use Sauce Labs, Browser Stack or something to run tests remotely, the round-trips add up **a lot**. I've reduced the time it takes to run large test suites in half by combining multiple Selenium calls into a single `execute_script` (or `execute_script_async`) call.